# Jquery not working on website, but working on another with same code

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 websites, both with the same code which display a Jquery speedometer.  On one of the websites the speedometer doesnt show, but the other one does.  There doesnt seem to be any jquery errors on the console and I am at a loss.

The div where it loads is #stresstotal

Speedometer working
http://www.beatinganger.com/node/353/done

Speedometer not working
http://www.paleolife.co.uk/pi/81-290593477

Any help would be appreciated.

**Page not working**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.paleolife.co.uk/sites/default/files/js_injector/js_injector_5.js?m1v0du"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.paleolife.co.uk/sites/default/files/js_injector/js_injector_7.js?m1v0du"></script>
```

Page working

```
<script>

    $(function(){
        $('#stresstotal').speedometer();
            $('#stresstotal').speedometer({ percentage: $('.speedometer').val() || 0 });
    });



</script>
<script src="http://www.beatinganger.com/scripts/jquery.speedometer.js"></script>
```

They are the same code just in different file names.

Comment: If you search the source of the first page for the string `speed` you get lots of results, including a JavaScript object and the filenames of a number of scripts. If you do the same on the second page, you don't. This suggests that the statement *both with the same code* is incorrect. Add the code that generates the widget to the other page.

Comment: Can't you tear the page apart to just to put up an example showing the relevant code?  http://sscce.org/

Comment: The relevant code (html and js) are the same, however the speedometer js inside a file that is named differently than the other page.

Comment: js_injector_7.js and js_injector_5.js are the speedometer js code, on the one it is working, one of the js files is actually written directly into the head

Comment: jquery.speedometer.cs is never loaded in the second page, thats why it don't work.

Comment: @daniloquio, if that's the reason, then post it as an answer below.

Comment: @Sparky672 you're right. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jquery.speedometer.js` is never loaded in the second page, thats why it don't work.

The line:

```
<script src="http://www.beatinganger.com/scripts/jquery.speedometer.js"></script>
```

is not present in `js_injector_5.js` or in `js_injector_7.js`.

I'm sure that there are other references on the working page missing on the problematic one, so make a detailed check to guarantee that both sites resolve the same references -even if referenced from different places-.